# Remove double legend plotly in R

Tags: r, legend, r-plotly

I don't know why I have a double legend.
How to remove the second legend where it is written  `Aa`

Code:

```
city = c("paris", "lyon", "lyon", "marseille", "lille", "toulouse", "bordeaux")
start = c("2018-08-04", "2018-07-25", "2018-07-30", "2018-07-29", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-03")
max = c(36.4, 37.2, 38.4, 37.4, 36.7, 34.9, 34.8)
duration = c(4, 3,  8, 10,  5,  4,  3)

tab = data.frame(city, start, duration, max)
tab$duration = as.integer(tab$duration)
```

[image]

```
t <- list(
         family = "sans serif",
         size = 14,
         color = toRGB("grey50"))

bubbleplot <- plot_ly(tab, x = ~start, y = ~max,
                      text = ~paste(duration, "jours"), 
                      color = ~city,  mode='markers+text'
                      )
bubbleplot = bubbleplot %>% add_markers(
                            marker = list(size = ~duration*4, opacity = 0.7,
                                          sizemode = "diameter"))
bubbleplot <- bubbleplot %>% add_text(textfont = t, textposition = "inside")

bubbleplot
```

[image]

Comment: [Same question on plotly community forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-remove-aa-from-the-legend/41506): "Please note that in the upcoming v2 of the library, this Aa text will no longer appear in the legend "

Answer (score 0):

Use the following,

```
 t <- list(
  family = "sans serif",
  size = 14,
  color = toRGB("grey50"))

bubbleplot <- plot_ly(tab, x = ~start, y = ~max,
                      text = ~paste(duration, "jours"), 
                      color = ~city,  mode='markers+text'
) 

bubbleplot = bubbleplot %>% add_markers(
  marker = list(size = ~duration*4, opacity = 0.7,
                sizemode = "diameter"))  %>% add_text(x = ~start, y = ~max,
                                                      text = ~paste(duration, "jours"), textfont = t, textposition = "inside", data = tab, inherit = F)

bubbleplot
```

Comment: When I execute your code, I don't have the text in the bubble.

Comment: Modified the answer, but you will get a single text legend